# Intercept method exceptions in java

Tags: java, reflection

I wanted to know if it is possible to make something like that to intercept errors when calling a method and how, or if there is something already created similar... example so you can understand better.

```
ErrorMessageHandler.intercept(RepositoryManager.find(Types.valueOf("NONE"), "test")
            .interceptExceptionWithMessage(Enum.class, (e) -> "can't find enum " + e)
            .interceptExceptionWithMessage(IllegalStateException.class, (e) -> "can't find repository " + e)
            .interceptExceptionWithMessage(NullPointerException.class, (e) -> "name can't be null " + e)
            .invoke(); 


// This is the method im using on example above from RepositoryManager.class
RepositoryManager find(Types type, String name) {
     if (name == null)
         throw new NullPointerException();

     return VALUES.stream()
                  .filter(v -> v.getName.equals(name))
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException());
}
```

The example above will intercept the valueOf exception because there is no Types.NONE, but if it were valid it will check other exceptions, example: if the Types is valid but the name is null then it will intercept the NullPointerException throw, and interceptExceptionWithMessage also debugs to console with the custom message u put in it, example "can't find enum " or other... is possible make something like that, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to pass a lambda to `intercept`, which will need to be at the end of your call chain. What specific problem are you having with your code?

Comment: @tgdavies I haven't coded the example above, is just something i write because is a idea i have... so now i want to know if is possible to code something similar in java and how.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615924/intercept-method-exceptions-in-java?noredirect=1

Comment: It seems to me you're looking for try-catch and standard exception handling, but it also seems to me I'm likely wrong.

Comment: You might want to look at Vavr `Try` and its `mapFailure` options.